# RTC collector API not fetching latest records

Tags: java, rational-team-concert

I am trying to fetch work items data from the `Rest API` of the `RTC collector` for a particular project. However, the `Rest API` provides me a max of initial 1000 records of work items based on project id. As a result, I am not fetch the latest records.
Is there any way I could apply filter to `Rest API` for type or records or any other way to get the latest records based on type of work item.